# Adding onItemClickListener to each listview item while items are still being added

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-listview

I'm not really sure how to explain this problem, but I'll do my best. I have an app that records sound and after you're done recording, you have to rename the file and then the file is added to listview in another activity.

I have tab layout, so adding files to listview is a little bit more complicated, here's how I do it:

Recording activity:

```
if (getParent() instanceof FileNameProvider) {
    ((FileNameProvider) getParent()).onNewFileName(newFileName);
}
```

Tab layout activity:

```
public void onNewFileName(Editable filename) {
    LocalActivityManager activityManager = getLocalActivityManager();
    getTabHost().setCurrentTabByTag("Library");
    RecordedLibrary recLib = (RecordedLibrary) activityManager.getActivity("Library");
    recLib.setFileName(filename);
}
```

And finally, I get the new filename in my library (listview) activity:

```
public void setFileName(final Editable filename) {
    Log.d("2", "Set filename from first activity " + filename);
}
```

So, everytime I set a filename, it's automatically added to listview with this code:

```
public void setFileName(final Editable filename) {
    Log.d("2", "Set filename from first activity " + filename);

    //LISTVIEW (declared globally)
    fileNames.add(filename.toString()); 
    listView = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.mainListView);
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, fileNames);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Now what I want to do next is to also automatically add onItemClickListener for each item added. I know I could do this with switch statement like this:

```
switch (position){
    case 0:
        //code
        break;
}
```

But this isn't possible in my case because everytime I record a file, this file has a different path, since there's a different name. This is how I tried to do it:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), filename, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

    });
```

This doesn't work either because everytime I add a new file to the listview, the filename variable changes, so this code works only as long as I only add one item to listview. As soon as I add the second item to listview, toast will show the second file's name no matter which item I click.

I hope everyone understand's the problem. Let me know if I should add any more info.

**SOLUTION:**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), fileNames.get(arg2), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

    });
```

**As you can see, I simply changed the 'filaname' to 'fileNames.get(arg2)', please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18080869/2454356) for more details.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should NOT create and set a new ListAdapter each and every time you set a file name.

Adapters should only be created once and attached to a ListView once per lifecycle, which is probably why the second time you add a file, only the second file name is being returned. You are overriding the previous Adapter and data each time you call `setFileName`.

Comment: correct, and also in onItemClick you write the "filename" into the toast which was not delivered by the callback (I don't know where you got it from), however you should check the position (arg2) instead and get the filename from the respective data in your adapter

Comment: @AlexFu sorry, I just deleted my comment because I just did exactly that a minute before you replied, however the application still works the same way. I'm trying to do what jpm told me to do now, but I'm not sure how to achieve that. How do I check the position (arg2) and get the filename that way?

Comment: @jpm How do I check the position and get the filename from the data? I'm new to android programming so I'd appreciate some explanation.

Comment: @Matthew You should really [read the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) on this instead of relying on other people... Because of the ambiguous argument name, `arg2`, it's hard to know what to do with it. But by reading the docs and knowing that `arg2` is the position of the list item that was clicked, you can now use that info to get the filename you need... _Hint: The position of the list item should also be the position of the filename in your ArrayList._

Comment: @AlexFu thanks a lot! I've only started programming about 3 months ago so I'm still not thinking really good as a programmer, that's why I have a hard time understanding explanation and reading docs. But I'm hoping to get better at it as soon as possible :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add an `onClickListener` to every object in your list. As you indicated above that you're use a seperate activity to house your `ListView` I would (1) make that activity extend `ListActivity` (2) use `onListItemClick`

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

}
```

This way if you keep track of which file is added in which order (above you mention you're using an `ArrayList` to store file names) you could use the position or id value (depending on what kind of adapter is backing your list) to retrieve the file name. You can play around with which collection works best for retrieving the file data (though the array list probably works fine if you're adding and removing these values in a predictable order).

You can also do this using the `onItemClickListener` you have in place. Arg2 is the position of the item in the list. Just take that value and get the file you need from the `ArrayList` storing the file extention.